# How can i add an extra object to a mesh/armature that i have forgotten to add to the mesh before i added the bones?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

i have a character that i parented to an armature but now i forgot to add one little object on the head beforehand. now i have tried parenting the extra object to the character and it works fine to move it in objectmode but whenever i move it in pose mode (and render it) the extra object wont come along
can anyone help me with this? :)

[image: i want the pink tube to be part of the head]

Answer (score 0):

i couldn`t find where to delete a question but i have the answer for the problem, the object was still a bezier curve that's why it didnt work

Comment: I propose you do not delete the question, and enhance a bit your answer as it can be useful for others